# Full node initialization error : NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: iri-node

I've got this error when i tried to launch a full node on a mac OS laptop running java 9.0.1. Any tougths on how to fix-it please ?

```
12/05 19:58:34.267 [main] INFO  com.iota.iri.IRI - Welcome to IRI 1.4.1.2
Exception in thread "main" 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/ValidationException
    at com.iota.iri.IRI.main(IRI.java:55)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.ValidationException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 1 more
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It requires java 8 and don't run on java 9. So you have to downgrade java and it can be tricky:

Be sure to uninstall java 9 completely with the following command lines :

```
sudo rm -rf "/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin"
sudo rm -rf "/Library/PreferencePanes/JavaControlPanel.prefPane"
sudo rm -rf "~/Library/Application Support/Java"
```

Once done you install java 8 : http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre8-downloads-2133155.html

To check your version of java : open a terminal and use :

```
java --version
```

Answer (score 3):

Actually the problem occurred with Java 9. downgrading the JRE to version 8 seems fixing the issue